# windows.open - strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html, window, dhtml

I'm using `window.open()` to open a new window in a desired size and location. After the content inside the window loaded, the window just jumps to another location and changes its size.

I'm using the standard api of `window.open()` using this function:

```
function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
  return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}
```

Any ideas why the window loses its location / size ?

Comment: what browser have you tested it it?

Comment: chrome. I'm using it to open twitter sharing. maybe it's something they do that sets different sizes ...